# If UICollectionView cell contains specific text, update the size of the cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, chat

I'm creating a chat app. Inside the messages I convert GIF-links into GIFs that is showing.

Unfortunately the `UICollectionViewCell` doesn't update in size, since it loads the URL as Text at first. I'm using this code:

```
if message.text.hasSuffix(".gif") {
        cell.bubbleView.backgroundColor = .clear
        let gifURL : String = message.text
        let imageURL = UIImage.gifImageWithURL(gifURL)
        let gifImageView = UIImageView(image: imageURL)
        gifImageView.frame = CGRect(x: cell.frame.size.width, y: 0, width: cell.frame.size.width , height: 150)
        gifImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        cell.titleLabel.text = ""

        cell.addSubview(gifImageView)
    }
```

But how can I change the size of the `UICollectionViewCell` to my needs without reloading the cell itself (Because then the cell will still have the same text, and will then fetch the Image again - and so i'll end up in a catch22)

Comment: you can use the sizeForItemAtIndexPath method to give the size to the cell

Comment: Well your simplest solution would be not loading image again after reloading cell. In other words create a caching mechanism in your UIImageView with imageURL method. If the image exist in cache it will take it from there. Alternatively, try SDWebImage, it has all the functionality you're asking for out of the box.